# R - Join two dataframes on column containing part of string

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge

I have two dataframes

df1

```
  Gate  Set
1  1  PIP D04 LMI1 975
2  6  PIP D06 LMI1 363
3 Time  PIP d08 LMI1 wk7 539
```

and

df2

```
    ID     Weeks
1  d01       6
2  d04       8
3  d06       9
4  d08       19
```

that I would like to merge. As you can see, the strings in df2$ID come back as part of the string in df1$Set. 
I would like to join the two dataframes in a way that the string is matched and the corresponding value in df2$Weeks is attached in a new column. Something like this:

```
  Gate       Set             Weeks
1  1    PIP D04 LMI1 975      8
2  6    PIP D06 LMI1 363      9
3 Time  PIP d08 LMI1 wk7 539  19
```

I tried an approach where I looped with a function that split up the string that didn't work.

```
test_day <- unlist(strsplit(df[,2][1], ""))
test_day <- paste(test_day[c(5:7)], collapse = "")
```

Edit: Here the dput outputs for both dataframes:

df1:

```
structure(list(Gate = structure(c(1L, 24L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 13L, 
1L, 21L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
10L, 14L, 15L, 22L, 1L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 
11L, 1L, 24L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 22L, 1L, 12L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 24L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 
13L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 22L, 1L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
1L, 11L, 1L, 24L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 22L, 1L, 
12L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 24L, 1L, 23L, 
1L, 13L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 22L, 1L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 24L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 22L, 
1L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 24L, 1L, 
23L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 
9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 22L, 1L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 24L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 
20L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 
22L, 1L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 24L, 
1L, 23L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 19L, 
1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 22L, 1L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 24L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 21L, 
1L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 14L, 
15L, 22L, 1L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 
24L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
19L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 22L, 1L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 24L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 
21L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 
14L, 15L, 22L, 1L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 11L, 
1L, 24L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 19L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 22L, 1L, 12L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 24L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 13L, 
1L, 21L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
10L, 14L, 15L, 22L, 1L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 
11L, 1L, 24L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 22L, 1L, 12L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 24L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 
13L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 22L, 1L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
1L, 11L, 1L, 24L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 22L, 1L, 
12L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 24L, 1L, 23L, 
1L, 13L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 22L, 1L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 24L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 22L, 
1L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 24L, 1L, 
23L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 
9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 22L, 1L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 24L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 
20L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 
22L, 1L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 24L, 
1L, 23L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 19L, 
1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 22L, 1L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 24L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 21L, 
1L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 14L, 
15L, 22L, 1L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 
24L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
19L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 22L, 1L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 24L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 
21L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 
14L, 15L, 22L, 1L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 11L, 
1L, 24L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 19L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 22L, 1L, 12L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 24L, 1L, 23L, 1L, 13L, 
1L, 21L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
10L, 14L, 15L, 22L, 1L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 
11L), .Label = c("All", "B cell", "CD14+ CD16+", "CD14++ CD16-", 
"CD14++ CD16+", "CD16-CD56+ NK", "CD16-CD56+ NK bright", "CD16+CD56+ NKdim", 
"CD3-", "CD3+CD56- Tcells", "CD4+CD25++", "CD4+CD8- Tc", "CD45+", 
"CD56+CD3- NK cells", "CD56+CD3+ NKT cells", "CD8-CD4- Tc", "CD8+CD4- Tc", 
"CD8+CD4+ Tc", "Lymphocytes", "Monocytes", "Neutrophils", "non NK(T) cells", 
"Singlets", "Time"), class = "factor"), Set = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L), .Label = c("d31 wk 9.5 LMI1 168", "PIP D04 LMI1 975", "PIP D06 LMI1 363", 
"PIP d08 LMI1 wk7 539", "PIP d10 LMI1 wk10.4 540", "PIP D12 DPMC LMI1 789", 
"PIP d13 6.2wk LMI1", "PIP D15 LMI1 316", "PIP D19 LMI1 319", 
"PIP D21 LMI1 518", "PIP D22 LMI1 519", "PIP D23 LMI1 520", "PIP D26 LMI1 912", 
"PIP d39 wk 9.2 LMI1 094", "PIP d46 wk 8 LMI1 550", "d56 LMI1 14.3wk 2018-06-19 771", 
"PIP D05P LMI1 981", "PIP D07 LMI1 367", "PIP d11 LMI1 wk14 541", 
"PIP d14 LMI1 14wk 136", "PIP D18 LMI1 318", "PIP D20 LMI1 321", 
"PIP D24 LMI1 521", "PIP D25 LMI1 527", "PIP D27 LMI1 911", "PIP d47 wk 15.3 LMI1 554"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Gate", "Set"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-972L))
```

and df2:

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 
68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 
81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 
94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 
106L, 107L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L), .Label = c("d01", 
"d02", "d03", "d04", "d05B", "d05P", "d06", "d07", "d08", "d09", 
"d10", "d100", "d101", "d102", "d103", "d104", "d105", "d106", 
"d11", "d12", "d13", "d14", "d15", "d16", "d17", "d18", "d19", 
"d20", "d21", "d22", "d23", "d24", "d25", "d26", "d27", "d28", 
"d29", "d30", "d31", "d32", "d33", "d34", "d35", "d36", "d37", 
"d38", "d39", "d40", "d41", "d42", "d43", "d44", "d45", "d46", 
"d47", "d48", "d49", "d50", "d51", "d52", "d53", "d54", "d55", 
"d56", "d57", "d58", "d59", "d60", "d61", "d62", "d63", "d64", 
"d65", "d66", "d67", "d68", "d69", "d70", "d71", "d72", "d73", 
"d74", "d75", "d76", "d77", "d78", "d79", "d80", "d81", "d82", 
"d83", "d84", "d85", "d86", "d87", "d88", "d89", "d90", "d91", 
"d92", "d93", "d94", "d95", "d96", "d97", "d98", "d99"), class = "factor"), 
    Weeks = c(6.7, 8.4, 6.3, 8, 15.9, 15.9, 8.9, 16.3, 7, 8, 
    10.6, 14, 10, 6.3, 14, 6.9, NA, 16, 16, 7.3, 13, 5, 6, 7, 
    14.4, 14.4, 7, 13.4, 6, 6, 14.3, 9.7, 14.3, 5.7, 7.3, 8.1, 
    6, 15.4, 7.4, 9.3, 13.6, 5.9, 5.4, 7.7, 13, 13.3, 8, 15.4, 
    16, 7, 14.1, 6.7, 13.1, 6, 6, 10.6, 14.4, 5, 6.7, 7.9, 12.4, 
    7.6, 14, 6, 13.6, 13.6, 7.3, 9, 16, 16.3, 4.7, 5, 5.9, 6, 
    8, 11.6, 6, 6.4, 8.1, 8.1, 7, 7.3, 9.6, 13.3, 6, 5, 11, 11, 
    17, 6.3, 8.3, 11.3, 14.3, 4.9, 5.9, 8.4, 5.4, 7, 15.6, 6.1, 
    4.7, 10.9, 10.4, 6, 7.3, 8.9, 11)), .Names = c("ID", "Weeks"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -107L))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you share your data with `dput`? Post output of `dput(df1)` and `dput(df2)` at the end of your question.

Comment: I added both dput outputs for the dfs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `regex_left_join` from the library `fuzzyjoin` which allows merging datasets on regular expression matches of column entries:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
regex_left_join(df1, df2, by = c("Set" = "ID"), ignore_case = T) %>%
    select(-ID)
#  Gate                  Set Weeks
#1    1     PIP D04 LMI1 975     8
#2    6     PIP D06 LMI1 363     9
#3 Time PIP d08 LMI1 wk7 539    19
```

---

### Sample data

```
df1 <- read.table(text =
    "  Gate  Set
1  1  'PIP D04 LMI1 975'
2  6  'PIP D06 LMI1 363'
3 Time  'PIP d08 LMI1 wk7 539'", header = T)

df2 <- read.table(text =
    "    ID     Weeks
1  d01       6
2  d04       8
3  d06       9
4  d08       19", header = T)
```

---

### Update

Using your updated sample data

```
regex_left_join(df1, df2, by = c("Set" = "ID"), ignore_case = T) %>%
    select(-ID)
                    Gate                            Set Weeks
1                    All               PIP D04 LMI1 975   8.0
2                   Time               PIP D04 LMI1 975   8.0
3                    All               PIP D04 LMI1 975   8.0
4               Singlets               PIP D04 LMI1 975   8.0
5                    All               PIP D04 LMI1 975   8.0
6                  CD45+               PIP D04 LMI1 975   8.0
7                    All               PIP D04 LMI1 975   8.0
8            Neutrophils               PIP D04 LMI1 975   8.0
9                    All               PIP D04 LMI1 975   8.0
10             Monocytes               PIP D04 LMI1 975   8.0
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
df1[, ID := tolower(gsub(".+([dD]\\d{2}).+", "\\1", Set))]
df1
#   Gate                  Set  ID
#1:    1     PIP D04 LMI1 975 d04
#2:    6     PIP D06 LMI1 363 d06
#3: Time PIP d08 LMI1 wk7 539 d08
df2[df1, on = .(ID)]
#    ID Weeks Gate                  Set
#1: d04     8    1     PIP D04 LMI1 975
#2: d06     9    6     PIP D06 LMI1 363
#3: d08    19 Time PIP d08 LMI1 wk7 539

# with merge()
merge(df1, df2, by = "ID")
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- fread("Gate,  Set
  1,  PIP D04 LMI1 975
  6,  PIP D06 LMI1 363
 Time,  PIP d08 LMI1 wk7 539")

df2 <- fread("ID     Weeks
d01       6
d04       8
d06       9
d08       19")
```